# Add custom tooltip for range slider using tailwind css in react

Tags: html, css, react-hooks, tailwind-css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCD3m.png)

how to achieve some like in the image with tailwaind css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div className="relative group">
  <Component />
  {text && (
    <div
      className='absolute left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 border mt-2 transition-all ease-in-out duration-200 border-blue-gray w-125 text-center rounded-tiny p-2 text-2xs z-50 bg-white opacity-0 scale-y-0 group-hover:opacity-100 group-hover:scale-y-100'
              >
      <span>{text}</span>
      <div
        className='absolute w-2.5 h-2.5 border-blue-gray border-t border-r transform left-1/2 -translate-1/2 bg-white'
      />
    </div>
  )}
</div>
```

"Component" is your sliders button in this case

Comment: Hello @PCPbiscuite https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-sammet-je7c1?file=/src/App.js:0-1142 can u please tell me how can i make this slider responsive on all screens i mean the image should follow the slider thumb

Comment: @SaiCharan get rid of useEffect and in your bubble do something like this
<div className="buble" style={{left: `${value}%`}}>
        <img
          src={
            "https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/153-1534932_thumbs-up-png-green-clipart.png"
          }
          style={{ height: "30px", widhth: "30px" }}
          alt="trail image"
        />
        {value}
      </div>

Also, I suggest you use transform property here it would help with the positioning a bit

Comment: @SaiCharan You shouldn't be using querySelector and direct DOM manipulations, it is considered an anti-pattern in React

Comment: Thankyou So much @PCPbiscuit i will try in my project